# Liquid where with and or or

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I use liquid syntax with Jekyll. I use

```
{% assign projects = (site.pages | where: "categories" , "project") %}
```

For filter the pages with that categories. How can I add another criteria as "and" or "or"???

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I find the solution...very easy. Simple I put

```
site.categories['project'] | where: 'featured',true
```

and it filter with and and type